# PYTHON: how to remove list's elements from a string after checking they are in the string

Tags: python

i am given a list of strings(words) and a non-spaced string, what i am supposed to do with them is:

1. check wether the string in the list is in the non-spaced string
2. in case it is remove the found words
3. give a list that has all the words found in lexicographic order
4. give the most found word, in case there are two words that appear the same number of times just give the one that comes first in lexicographic order
5. give a tuple of the unfound words

example:

```
list=['cat','dog','mouse']

string='mousecatmousemousecatcat'
```

the answer should be:

`(['mouse','cat'],'cat')` and the list has to become `['dog']`

example:

- `list=['ala','cena','elica','nave','luce','lana','vela']`
- `string='lucenavelanavelanaveelica'`

the answer should be:

`(['luce','nave','lana','vela','elica'],'nave')`  and the list becomes `['ala','cena']`

i now am at this point:

def function(lista, testo):

```
conto=0
val=''
presenti=list(filter(lambda x: x in testo, lista))
non_presenti= (set(lista)-set(presenti))
if non_presenti >0:
    return tuple(non_presenti)
else:
    return list(non_presenti)
#tuple(filter(lambda x: x not in testo, lista))


for i in range(1,len(lista)):
    a=testo.count(lista[i-1])
    if conto <= a:
        conto=a
        val=lista[i-1]
print(type(presenti), type(val), type(non_presenti))

return presenti, val,non_presenti
```

here is the final code, i am sorry if i did not explain myself right, i am still new to this forum...:

def es3(lista, testo):

```
dizionario_iniziale={}
a=0
b=0
c=0
ripetute=0
while a !=len(testo):
    a= b + len(lista[c])
    if testo[b:a]== lista[c]:
        b=a
        dizionario_iniziale[lista[c]]= dizionario_iniziale.get(lista[c],0)+1
        c=0
    else:
        c +=1    

for i in dizionario_iniziale:
    if ripetute < dizionario_iniziale[i]:
        ripetute= dizionario_iniziale[i]
        parola=i
        meno_ripetuta=i
    elif ripetute==dizionario_iniziale[i]:
        if parola<i:
            meno_ripetuta=parola
        else:
            meno_ripetuta=i

chiavi=dizionario_iniziale.keys()
for i in chiavi:
    lista.remove(i)
return list(dizionario_iniziale.keys()), meno_ripetuta
```

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: Why is the 2nd result `['ala','cena']`? There *is* a "cena" in "lu**cena**velanavelanaveelica". Also, none of your output lists are sorted lexicographically.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. You posted a list of requirements, but no code nor clear question so it's impossible to tell what you expect, so please edit your question to make your question clear.

Comment: This is an interesting question, it reads more like a coding challenge or interview coding test than a question about programming that's why it's getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1=['cat','dog','mouse']
string='mousecatmousemousecatcat'

def some_func(input_list, string):
    occurance_list = []
    most_counted = ""
    num = 0
    for i in input_list:
        if string.count(i) > num:
            most_counted = i
            num = string.count(i)
        if string.count(i) > 0:
            occurance_list.append(i)
    not_occured  = list(set(input_list) - set(occurance_list))
    return occurance_list, most_counted, not_occured

print(some_func(list1, string))


list2=['ala','cena','elica','nave','luce','lana','vela']

string='lucenavelanavelanaveelica'

print(some_func(list2, string))
```

Outputs:

```
>>>(['cat', 'mouse'], 'cat', ['dog'])
>>>(['cena', 'elica', 'nave', 'luce', 'lana', 'vela'], 'nave', ['ala'])
```

Comment: this code works fine but it still gives words that take as a suffix the last letters of the previus word...i need to fix this problem but i don't know how to

Comment: @LRA98 give me an example and I will look into it.